# Java Installation Wizard Constantly Interrupted

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java 7 Update Issues - save my sanity](https://superuser.com/questions/464694/java-7-update-issues-save-my-sanity)

I have been trying to log into a work presentation for 3 days - at log in the site keeps prompting me to download Java 7u6 but when I follow the prompts to install Java it comes up with an error message reading "Installation Wizard was interrupted please run later" or something similar.

This is what I have tried so far:

- downloading JavaRa to uninstall previous versions (did not work very well)
- manually checking whole of C drive and deleting all Java files/folders
- downloading an offline version
- clearing cookies/temp files
- shutting down laptop then uninstalling Java then shutting down again then installing newer version
- uninstalling Java7u4 and installing Java 6 (this installation actually worked but don't think it was compatible with the work site as it kept prompting me to install Java 7
- checked that the applets are enabled
- downloading through Java and Oracle sites, downloading through JavaRa command

Please note the following details:

- OS is Windows (Vista 32 bit)
- Browser is Internet Explorer

I am not great with computers and am frustrated beyond belief as am missing out on important tech training modules. I have googled for 3 days and tried all sorts of things and nothing works. The Java troubleshooting for the error message (Installation Wizard was interrupted please run later) just says to check the applets are enabled (they are).

MY QUESTION IS - WHAT IS INTERRUPTING THE INSTALLATION WIZARD???  WHY WON'T JAVA INSTALL???

If anyone could help I would be very grateful!

Thank you for reading!

Cat

PS - When I was going through C drive I noticed an unfamiliar folder called "java".  I checked the creation date and it was the day my laptop got serviced.  Java was updated on this day to the 7u4 version.  I'm assuming the IT guy created the file and updated Java.  I have just deleted this whole folder as the 7u4 version would not uninstall through "Program Files".  Could his mucking about with Java have anything to do with the Great Java Installation Problem???

Comment: With all the installing and uninstalling, can you open up a command line (Start button, type "cmd", press Enter).  Once the window opens, type "java" (no quotes).  What is the output of that test?

Comment: The installation is running, and Java is acting up.  I wonder if something is running.  Hold down Ctrl + Alt + Del, and open the Task Manager.  Under the "Processes" tab, click the button to show processes from all users.  Sort the list by "Image Name".  Are there any "java" or "javaw" processes running?

Comment: When installing, right-click the installer and "Run as Administrator".  It's possibly a permission thing stopping the installer.